# Installing mysql-server 8 - stuck at "Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)"

Tags: server, virtualbox, mysql, vagrant

I'm trying to install mysql-server on a fresh vagrant box based on Ubuntu 22.04.

That's my Vagrantfile.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/jammy64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
  config.vm.hostname = "test.local"
end
```

After vagrant up, all I do is apt update && upgrade then sudo apt install mysql-server.
The installation it's getting stuck at "Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I ended up installing mariaDB

Answer (score 0):

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127891/cant-install-mysql-on-pure-ubuntu-20-04

I added this in a batch script before installing mysql

```
# Add swap space on Ubuntu 20 (1000MB)
sudo fallocate -l 1G /.swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /.swapfile
sudo mkswap /.swapfile
sudo swapon /.swapfile
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
echo '/.swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```